# Proxy SSLv3 to TLSv1.x

Tags: proxy

Our main servers supports HTTPs with TLSv1.0 minimum. On the other hand we have special clients that have SSLv3 maximum.

What can I do to support those clients?

Notes regarding those clients:

- It is a special legacy hardware, and we don't have access to the firmware.
- Clients are running inside a controlled environment and we don't have issue to use SSLv3, but can't communicate over HTTP due to the firmware restrictions.
- I need some kind proxy to handle SSLv3 requests and forward it to our main server.

Comment: This is called a reverse proxy, and any modern web server can do it, such as nginx or Apache httpd.

Comment: as i know, nginx doesn't accept SSLv3 anymore